# Which header to include in order to use std::streamoff and std::streamsize?

Tags: c++, std

I want to use the `std::streamoff` and `std::streamsize` types without pulling a huge part of the iostream library. For now, I'm including the `<iostream>` header. Is there a better way to proceed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are defined in header `<ios>`

Answer (score 3):

`#include <ios>` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, though the site is not perfect, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streamoff/) is enough if you want to know the exact header where something resides in. It's in the upper-right corner between the angle brackets, `<ios>` in this case.

Comment: I visited cplusplus.com many times but I've never seen the little angle brackets. You deserve an investigator badge !